Python Text-To-Speech Logic making weird pronunciations
When I used windows this code ran perfectly. It has been 2 weeks since I switched to fedora. I am not sure what is making it behave like so.
import pyttsx3
from colorama import Fore, Style

#Setting up Rate
RATE = 175
engine = pyttsx3.init() 
engine.setProperty('rate',RATE)

#Volume
VOLUME = 0.85 #Must be between 0 to 1. A float too.
engine.setProperty('volume',VOLUME)

#Voice ID
engine.setProperty('voice',engine.getProperty('voices')[0].id) #id 1 for female, 0 for male

def Speak(speech):
    print(Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX+speech+Style.RESET_ALL)
    engine.say(speech)
    engine.runAndWait()
    return

This is output of my Small Language Model.
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:567:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1000:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1000:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:567:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1000:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2722:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1000:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
You are requested to wait for a while
Listening Now


It pronounced yo ar requested to wait for a while
With the female voice it pronounces more worse.
yo r reqsted to wait for a wee le
This sounds very glitching. I am not sure what to do now and asking for help.
I will like to say I don't have pulseaudio but have espeak which is used by pythonttsx3
I found a similar issue on Ubuntu Forum but JACK is already good here. Also it broke my system components.
Last metadata expiration check: 3:13:25 ago on Thu 01 Aug 2024 12:29:13 PM +06.
Error: 
 Problem: problem with installed package pipewire-jack-audio-connection-kit-1.0.7-2.fc40.x86_64
  - package pipewire-jack-audio-connection-kit-1.0.7-2.fc40.x86_64 from @System conflicts with jack-audio-connection-kit-dbus provided by jack-audio-connection-kit-dbus-1.9.22-5.fc40.x86_64 from fedora
  - package pipewire-jack-audio-connection-kit-1.0.4-2.fc40.x86_64 from fedora conflicts with jack-audio-connection-kit-dbus provided by jack-audio-connection-kit-dbus-1.9.22-5.fc40.x86_64 from fedora
  - package pipewire-jack-audio-connection-kit-1.0.7-2.fc40.x86_64 from updates conflicts with jack-audio-connection-kit-dbus provided by jack-audio-connection-kit-dbus-1.9.22-5.fc40.x86_64 from fedora
  - conflicting requests
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)


Many people say to remove ALSA configurations but that moves the log but never fixed the issue.

You don't use the same text-to-speech synthesiser. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71709591/synthesizer-in-windows-sounds-much-better-than-in-linux-python-and-pyttsx3

@ThierryLathuille There are many tts availabe online. I will surely check that thing out but still wondering any solution directly for pysttx3.
